# How to send a verification email on registerUsingEmailPassword() in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I wan't when a user clicks sign up button an email verification is sent. So far with my code on signup an email verification is sent but user can't navigate to the next page (CircularProgressIndicator keeps on loading)

Here is my code

```
   onPressed: () async {
                  if (_regFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                     setState(() {
                    _isProcessing = true;
                  });

                    User? user = await FireAuth.registerUsingEmailPassword(
                      name: nameController,
                      email: _emailController.text,
                      password: _passwordController.text,
                    );        
                    if (user != null) {
                      bool EmailSent = user.sendEmailVerification() as bool;

                   //I think something is wrong here
                    if (EmailSent) {
                       Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ProfilePage(user: user),
                        ),
                        ModalRoute.withName('/'),
                      );  }

                    }  else{
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(' Account exists or Network problems'),
                         backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        ));}

                     setState(() {
                      _isProcessing = false;
                    });
                  
                }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendEmailVerification()` returns a `Future<void>` so `EmailSent` is not going to get set. You should `await` the verification call in a `try...catch` to handle the response.

More like this:

```
if (user != null) {
  try {
    await user.sendEmailVerification();
    /// sent successfully
    // TODO: put your navigation here
  } catch (e) {
    /// error sending verification
    // TODO: show snackbar
    // TODO: set _isProcessing to false
  }
}
```